# phpinfo running fine but mine file not working

Tags: php

I am using xamp 3.2.2. I start Apache and MySQL running successfully. If I browse "localhost" `http://localhost/dashboard/` opens. Also `http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php` works fine.

I make a folder under `xampp/htdocs` named `moni` and under `moni` I make a file `test.php`.

When I browse `http://localhost/moni/test.php`
it shows the error

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>   Error 404 localhost Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0g PHP/7.2.2

How can solve it?

Comment: check in your apache config where DocumentRoot is configured.  Do you have a 'dashboard' in htdocs ?